# Bot Framework on Messenger: Requesting thread control from Page Inbox not working

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, botframework, bots, facebook-messenger

I have developed a bot and set it as the Primary Receiver on my Page, and set the Inbox as the Secondary Receiver. Everything is working okay except that when I manually send a conversation from "Done" to the Inbox, after a user sends a new message it automatically resends the conversation to the Done folder and for the bot to answer.

This does not happen if I use the "pass_thread_control" graph API request, on these cases the handover works as expected.

I found this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol/request-thread-control#page_inbox

And it says that the Primary Receiver has to honor the request thread control event. My question is, how do I ensure this?

I am using the Azure Bot Framework, with .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Handover is not currently supported by the Bot Framework, and is not on the roadmap, however, it is something they might be able to look into in the future if there’s enough demand.